# Implicitly Converting an attribute of type Byte to String

Tags: python-3.x, scapy, packet

I've been trying to send some random **Association** frames with scapy. However, doing so, i am not able to dissect the packet in the correct manner. The **Dot11Elt** layer has field named **info** which is basically of type **Bytes**. How can i Convert this field from byte to normal string. So, the final result in the formed layer would be a string not bytes.

Here's some code to justify:

```
$ from scapy.all import *
$ layer = Dot11Elt(ID=0)   // For Storing SSID info
$ type(layer.info) == bytes
  True
```

Now, what i am trying to do is this:

```
$ from scapy.all import *
$ layer = Dot11Elt(ID=0)   // For Storing SSID info
$ type(layer.info) == bytes
  False
$ type(layer.info) == str
  True
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that ? You could simply `layer.info.decode()`

Comment: Have already tried that. But it doesn't work correctly. When the final pkt is dissected. It still shows the field as bytes not string.

Comment: That's very much expected. I don't understand the issue.

Comment: Basically, the problem is that when i send association request with ssid as `bytes` object. The Association response returns to be an `invalid` frame. This is with the latest version of scapy. However, if i turn my experiment with scapy version `2.4.0` with python `2`. The association request is sent with ssid as `str` object which returns a valid response.

Comment: Then please provide the whole packet in both versions (build the whole packet then call `bytes()` (Py3) or `str()` (Py2) on it), and how tou built it